# move the entire "mdsoft" folder (rbac) from vendor to backend (Yii2 advanced)

Tags: yii, yii2

I would like to migrate the entire "mdmsoft" folder (rbac) directly to the back end as it is currently in the vendor, is this possible?

What would I have to take into account to carry out this action?

Comment: possible is .. possible ...but why ?

Comment: **ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)**  Y U NO follow [**`THIS`**](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/blob/master/docs/guide/configuration.md)

Comment: because when doing a composer update, the modifications that I have made in the rbac would be lost. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Why not fork it?

Comment: That's why you shouldn't touch anything in `vendor` directory! If you want to modify something, extend base class and override it, never change base classes!